# How can Moshe be jealous of his Talmid Yehoshua?

Tags: midrash, moshe-rabbeinu, vayelech, yehoshua-joshua

The [Gemara in Sanhedrin 105b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.105b.15?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he) says

> דאמר רב יוסי בר חוני בכל אדם מתקנא חוץ מבנוותלמידו... ואיבעית אימא (במדבר כז, כג) ויסמוך את ידיו עליו ויצוהו
>
> as Rav Yosei bar Ḥoni says: A person is jealous of everyone except for his son and his student. Since their success reflects well upon him, he celebrates their success... And if you wish, say instead that it is derived from Moses: “And he laid his hands upon him and commanded him” (Numbers 27:23). God commanded Moses to lay only one hand upon Joshua, and instead he laid both hands upon him with all his strength.

One of the sets of people that the Gemara uses to prove that one is never jealous of their Talmid is Moshe and Yehoshua.

Is there any way to reconcile that with the [Midrash Rabbah in Devarim Rabbah 9:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Devarim_Rabbah.9.9?vhe=Daat_Devarim_Rabbah&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) that says that when Moshe saw Hashem speak to Yehoshua and he couldn't find out what Hashem said he proclaimed:

> !מאה מיתות ולא קנאה אחת
>
> "A hundred deaths and not one jealousy" (it would be better to die a hundred times than to experience this one feeling of jealousy.)

The Midrash is very explicit that Moshe was jealous of Yehoshua.

I am aware that there is a Machlokes in the Gemara and the Midrash can go like the other opinion in the Gemara, I'm just wondering if it is possible to reconcile the two. I also would like to know if anyone says explicitly that they're arguing. Thank you so much!

Comment: The Midrash ain't saying he was jealous it's stating that in such a situation it'd be better to die 100 times over then to be jealous... but no worries (says moshe) I cant be jealous- as chazar say in san 105

Answer (score 4):

[R. Kook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Isaac_Kook) notes this a responsum (printed in Tehumin Vol. V pg. 286), but explains that Moshe was jealous of Yehoshua, even though one isn't jealous of a student. That is, he understands that the Midrash and the Gemara do not contradict each other:

> ודבר ידוע שהצער הזה שיראה אדם את גדולתו ניטלת ממנו...שהוא גדול ועצום מאד עד שחז"ל במד"ר ס"פ וילך אמרו על משה לגבי יהושוע ואמר מאה מיתות ולא קנאה אחת, וזהו אפילו בתלמידו שאין אדם מקנא בו

Comment: Thanks! I'm not seeing this Sefer on Otzar Hachochma or Bar Ilan. Can you spell out the name in Hebrew or give me a link to find it inside? Thanks!

Comment: תחומין. It is a journal. I saw it on Bar Ilan myself, in the fifth volume, in an article entitled השגת גבול ברבנות. @Eliyahu

Comment: I'm not finding it on Bar Ilan, nor are the words you've written coming up on searches. What category is it under there if I browse?

Comment: Category is כתבי עת. select השגת גבול, then select R. Kook's article השגת גבול ברבנות. (version 23 of Bar Ilan). @Eliyahu

Comment: You are very welcome.  @Eliyahu